# Can't wrap my head around this this recursion example

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, multiplication, addition

So there is this recursion example in chap 3 of Eloquent JavaScript, it goes like this: Consider this puzzle: by starting from the number 1 and repeatedly either adding 5 or multiplying by 3, an infinite set of
numbers can be produced. How would you write a function that, given a number, tries to find a sequence of such additions and
multiplications that produces that number?

And the given code is..

```js
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
        find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
```

Now there are couple of things which I don't understand. Like very first time we call the function what is it going to return? is it going to return ***(1, "1")*** and just ignore the inner function ***find***?

and what is ***current*** and ***history*** in the example? I don't remember assigning their values?

Answer (score 1):

The first time you call `findSolution()` it will return the result of the last line of that function `find(1, "1")`. In that case "1" is history, which is being set by calling `find`. The value of `current` is 1, which was the first parameter in `find(1, "1")`

The important thing to understand is that you are calling a function that is calling a newly defined function `find`. The results of that function, which will recursively call itself is an exercise left to the reader (you). Whatever that result is will be returned by `findSolution`.